# How to export queries from Access 2003 and import to Access 2019

Tags: database, microsoft-access, data-transfer

A user of mine has an Access 2003 DB called *Receipts* and she needs to import all of the data within this DB to Access 2019. She said she was able to get everything migrated except for the Queries.

When I attempt to help her export the queries Access wants to import it as a table.

How do I export/migrate the queries she has to Access 2019?

Comment: "attempt to help her export the queries Access wants to import it as a table"- you probably exported the results of the queries, not the queries themselves. You need to copy the SQL code of queries to the new file.

Comment: Just copy/paste the SQL code?

Comment: Yes. SQL is enough to determine query.

Comment: I was able to copy/paste the SQL but it seems to "break" after being put into the new DB. Something about not able to find .dboReceipts.dbo

Comment: So you need to check what is .dboReceipts.dbo in the old database and how it's called in the new one.

Comment: All of the databases, forms, etc are the same. I was able to shift-click to select, then drag and drop to the new version. All I've had to do manually are the queries which I gave the same name as in the old version.

Answer (score 1):

There should be no **'export'** step in this process, only an **import** or a **conversion**.

---

If you merely need the existing database to be accessible using MS Access 2019, then opening a 2003 format `.mdb` in Access 2019 will automatically cause Access to ask whether you wish to convert the database to the `.accdb` format used by all later releases. This process is described in more detail [here](https://support.office.com/en-ie/article/convert-a-database-to-the-accdb-file-format-098ddd31-5f84-4e89-8f44-db0cf7c11acd). The conversion will create a `.accdb` file alongside your existing `.mdb` file and will **not** overwrite your existing database.

---

If instead you have an existing Access 2019 database into which you want to import the data & queries from your 2003 database, firstly, ensure that both databases are in `.accdb` format (following the method above) and then go to *`External Data > New Data Source > From Database > Access`*.

Select the `.accdb` file from which you wish to import the data and choose the **import** option (not link).

You can then click the tab for each object type and select the Tables, Queries, Forms, Reports, Macros & Modules that you wish to import into the Access 2019 database.

MS Access will notify you of any issues encountered during the import.

---

Alternatively, the more time-consuming approach would be to view the SQL code comprising each of the queries defined within your 2003 database, and copy the SQL for each query into a new query in your 2019 database, saving the query with the same name as that in your 2003 database.

If you decide to following this approach, you will need to ensure that the tables have already been imported, and then work from the innermost subqueries on which other queries depend.

Comment: Unfortunately the database is saved in a adp format. The option to save as "access database" is not available.

All the tables are the same, she was able to copy/paste between them. The only thing missing from the new DB is the queries (SQL in this case)

Comment: "Unfortunately the database is saved in a adp format" is the key information, as this feature was [removed](https://codekabinett.com/rdumps.php?Lang=2&targetDoc=access-adp-history) in ms access 2013.!